# Passing ListBox as a function paramaeter in C++

Tags: c++, winforms, function, listbox

I wonder if there's any way to pass the whole ListBox object to function as a parameter? Well, basically I only need listbox's selected index propertie, so I easily went around this by saving it's value to int and passing that int around. But just out of curiosity, I've wondered if you could pass ListBox as a parameter. I've tried:

`std::string TxtFileName(ListBox listBox);`

However this gives me `error C2065: 'ListBox' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: You don't want to pass it by value, pass by reference instead: `std::string TxtFileName(ListBox& listBox);` Also you probably miss something like `#include <ListBox.h>`

Comment: For starters, it looks like you're just missing an `include` or the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (before the `ListBox` or with `using`), and other than that, you'd probably want to pass a reference (or even better a const reference if you're not changing the `ListBox` within the function).

Comment: Passing visual component instances as parameters is very often done and, since such classes are intimately involved with the C GUI API and must outlive the functions that create them, are typically handled by pointers to them anyway.

Comment: Also, passing around data memebers by copying them to an int is messy, inflexible and is read-only - if you want to call a setter, you need access to the object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox` is not part of standard C++ (unlike, say, `int` or `std::string` or `std::cout`).

So it is unclear what `ListBox` you are talking about. Is it from an MS library? Or from a GUI toolkit like wxWidgets or QT? Or is it something completely different?

Generally, any GUI library I have ever used treated classes representing GUI elements as entity classes. Such classes refer to uniquely identifiable external resources, a thing on the screen in this case. They are not conceptually self-contained. Well-designed entity classes are **not copyable**, because it does not make sense to copy a unique external resource. What does it mean to *copy an object representing one particular list box on the screen*?

This is different from classes representing, say, numbers, matrices, text or dates. You can, for example, copy a `std::string`. A string does not refer to a unique resource. Text contents are not unique. You can have one string `"foo"` and another string `"foo"`. This different kind of class is called value class. Value classes *are* copyable.

The fact that your list box is not copyable (or should not be copyable) means that you cannot (or should not) pass it by value to a function. Passing by value copies an object. Even though the compiler may optimise away the copy, it does conceptually exist, so the class must support copying:

```
void f(ListBox listBox); // will not compile if class is well-designed,
                         // should not be done by you in either case
```

You must thus pass by reference. As you are only interested in retrieving some index from the list box, you can even pass by const reference, which is safer:

```
void f(ListBox const &listBox); // OK
```

Comment: Visual component instances are usually accessed by pointers or references anyway, eg 'ListBox^ listBox1 = gcnew ListBox;', (MSDN example).

Comment: @MartinJames: I do not have much experienced with managed C++, but apparently the rules are the same there. Which makes sense, as the distinction between entity classes and value classes exists in every language with classes that I know, even though the implications are different. For example, in Java, value classes tend to be immutable, whereas parameter passing is not affected (because there is no pass-by-value for classes anyway).